# Reverse dependency for a jar file

Tags: java, jar

Is it possible to find out all classes of a java project that use a certain jar file?

For example, how do I find all classes that use (import) classes from the xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the JAR file from your project setup and check for the classes that no longer compile.

I guess it is pretty similar for a "command line build" setup: first make sure you got a passing build with no errors; then drop the JAR; and count the errors. Done.

Well, that is true if none of your code uses reflection mechanisms to instantiate classes, objects on pure "from string" calls. Of course, this problem is much harder to solve (in the end it boils down to the halting problem; which is undecidable). Sure, you can apply heuristics and start grepping for reflection calls; and then try to find all the strings going into these calls.

Comment: Thought about it, but I would like a more elegant way.

Comment: Well, what could be more elegant than using a tool that already exists; without much additional coding (except maybe the parsing of error messages). How can creating your own tool be more elegant; compared to re-using what is already there (and proven, rock solid technology) I mind asking?!

Comment: Point and click; Export the result; see as a tree. You are only limited by your imagination.

Comment: I guess it is doable to create an eclipse plugin that would do that or you. But my point is still: how much work do you want to invest in a convenience function? How much work would be required to **get it right**? In that sense: of course - everything can be done. We are talking about software; so anything goes. Just a question of resources you are willing to invest.